# Show random TextField as a text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I want to make button, which pressed will show us random textfield (from 3 textfields: username, username2 or username3).
Currently I have something like this, but don't know how to make it possible.

```
struct Test: View {

/// @State private var names : ??? - I don't know what should be there
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State var username2: String = ""
    @State var username3: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Your name", text: $username)
                TextField("Your name2", text: $username2)
                TextField("Your name3", text: $username3)
                
                Button(action: randomName) {
                    Text("draw")
                            
                        }
                    
             }
                
                Text("names.text") /// it doesn't work
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func randomName() {
        let names = ["\(username)", "\(username2)", "\(username3)"]
    }
}
```

I have tried to add everything into first @State private var names, but nothing work properly. Maybe I am just trying in wrong way? Or it shouldn't be done by 'let names'?
I don't know and have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you just need to add randomName as State.

```
struct Example: View {

    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State var username2: String = ""
    @State var username3: String = ""
    @State var selectedName: String = "Initial Value"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Your name", text: $username)
                TextField("Your name2", text: $username2)
                TextField("Your name3", text: $username3)
                
                Button(action: randomName) {
                    Text("draw")
                }
                
                Text(selectedName) 
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
                    
          }
        }
        
        private func randomName() {
            let names = ["\(username)", "\(username2)", "\(username3)"]
            
            selectedName = names[Int.random(in: 0..<names.count)]
        }
}
```

Comment: It's not that I want. I want something like: user types all textfields (e.g: username = Claire, username2 = Rick, username3 = Micheal) and when we push the button then one of the entered names will be drawn as a Text

Comment: I think that is what you want

Comment: exactly! thank you for help. I have another (and last) question - what should I change (and how) in 'selectedName' to make it show in order? for example: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 (not in random way) - don't edit this code, just let me know in comments. Thank you!

Comment: First of all you need a variable for index. And you need to increase your index every single button tapped. And change that code selectedName = names[Int.random(in: 0..<names.count)] to             selectedName = names[index] After that increase your index, if your index equals the 2 because of your array has 3 elements. Then set zero

Answer (score 0):

The `username`,`username2` and `username3` properties are already strings.  No need to use string interpolation when you create your array.

Swift arrays have a handy `randomElement()` method.  The only wrinkle is that it returns an optional - It will return `nil` if the array is empty, so you need to handle this.  There are three ways:

1. You can use an `if let` to skip the code if the result is `nil`
2. You can use the nil-coalescing operator (`??`) to provide a default value if the result is `nil`
3. You can force unwrap using `!`. This is generally not a good approach, although it could work in this case because the array cannot be empty.

Option 1:

```
private func randomName() {
   let names = [username, username2, username3]
   if let randomName = names.randomElement() {
       selectedName = randomName
   }
}
```

Option 2:

```
private func randomName() {
   let names = [username, username2, username3]
   selectedName = names.randomElement() ?? ""
}
```

Option 3:

```
private func randomName() {
   let names = [username, username2, username3]
   selectedName = names.randomElement()!
}
```